# jQuery: Replace "&nbsp;" with normal spaces for window widths under 500px

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to replace all `&nbsp;` in my HTML files with normal spaces for window widths under `500px`.

To do this, I started with this code:

```js
window.onresize = xza;
window.onload = xza;

function xza() {
  let window_size = window.matchMedia("(max-width: 500px)");
  if (window_size.matches) {
    $("document.documentElement").find("&nbsp;").replaceWith(" ");
  } else {
    // nothing should happen or it should be like it was before
  }
```

Unfortunately, it doesn't work. Can someone help me please? :)

Comment: [jQuery .find()](https://api.jquery.com/find/) returns elements. `&nbsp;` is not an element. It's text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to keep in mind that `&nbsp;` isn't plain text. It's a special character (html entity). So to correctly replace it, you'll need to use unicode:

```
$(window).on("load resize", function(){
    if($(window).width() < 500){
        $("body").each(function() {
            var text = $(this).text();
            $(this).text(text.replace(/\u00a0/g, " "));
        });
    }
});
```

This will loop through each element inside `<body/>` and replace every `&nbsp;` with a normal space. Obviously I tested it before answering and it's working as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Try using regex

```js
window.onresize = xza;
window.onload = xza;

function xza() {
  let window_size = window.matchMedia("(max-width: 500px)");
  if (window_size.matches) {
  let doc = $(document)
    doc.text(doc.text().replace(/nbsp;/g, ' '))
  } else {
    // nothing should happen or it should be like it was before
  }
```

Comment: Tell us more about this problem. Does this only happen for screens below 500px? How are you viewing your site? With smartphone or developer tool?

Comment: I looked at it with Google Chrome and their developer tool. Nothing happened when I changed the window size under 500px with a lot of text and some "nbsp;".

Comment: I updated my answer, try changing $ ('document.documentElement') to $ (document)

Answer (score 0):

1. You don't need to call an extra function. jQuery `on load` and `on resize` do the job.
2. Making your code to look for all `&nbsp;` in the whole page will put a very heavy processing load on the page. try reducing it to a specific `div`. In order to do that simply replace the `$(document)` with `class name` or `id` of the specific div. Example: `$(".someClass")`

```js
$(window).on("load",function () {
  if ($(window).width() < 500) {
    $(document).text($(document).text().replace(/&nbsp;/g, ' '));
    console.log("Changing");
  }
});
$(window).on("resize",function () {
  if ($(window).width() < 500) {
    $(document).text($(document).text().replace(/&nbsp;/g, ' '));
    console.log("Changing");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p>Bla&nbsp;bla&nbsp;bla&nbsp;bla</p>
```

Comment: Hey, thank you! I tried your code, but unfortunately, it doesn't work at all. Why?

Comment: Nothing happens, the "&nbsp;" still exist for window sizes under 500px.